# How to prevent icon wrap in TextView in Android

Tags: android, html, kotlin, textview, imagespan

I added an image in the middle of the `TextView` using `ImageSpan`

[my_textview.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGM52.png)

But sometimes the text wraps the last word to the next line. And the last word is displayed separately from the icon, which should be with the text.

for example:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu0PU.png) 6470.3 mi and location icon should be together

Does it possible to fix it?

My code:

```
                val title = venue?.name + (if (!venue?.venue_name_indicator.isNullOrEmpty()) " - ${venue?.venue_name_indicator}" else "")

                val span = SpannableStringBuilder(title)
                if(venue?.distance != null && venue.distance.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_location)
                    icon?.setBounds(0, 0, 32, 32)
                    icon?.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.text_color_secondary))

                    span.append(" ")
                        .appendImage(icon!!)
                        .appendColor(context, context.getString(R.string.distance, venue.distance), R.color.text_color_secondary)
                }
                span.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, title.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
                venue_title?.text = span
```

method appendImage():

```
fun SpannableStringBuilder.appendImage(
    image: Drawable
): SpannableStringBuilder {
    val index = length
    append("\\u00A0")
    setSpan(ImageSpan(image), index, length, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    return this
}
```

As you see im using non-breakable space `\\u00A0` as a placeholder but that doesn't help

Comment: Try placing the non-breaking space between the image and the mileage. If you are OK with the space then you are done. If you need to space out then check for it in the layout of the TextView. If it is on the first line, then delete it. If it is on the second line, delete it and place a newline before the image. The key here is that you won't know how breaks will occur until the layout of the TextView. I would prefer a custom break strategy, but I don't know how that is done or if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, i added the non-breaking space between the image and icon and that helped! Also my problem is that i used '"\\u00A0"' instead of '"\u00A0"'